# Creating external tables in Azure SQL Datawarehouse

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, polybase

I wanted to load CSV into Azure SQL datawarehouse using polybase. I have created an external data source and external file format. I am not able to create external table because of Location error. I am attaching the script and screenshot below. Please let me know what appropriate code can be applied here.

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[exttest1]
( [description] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [industry] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [level] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [size] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [line_code] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](4000) NULL )
WITH
(
    LOCATION='store17/test2/SampleData.csv' , --my azure blob storage container
    DATA_SOURCE = ds1 ,
    FILE_FORMAT = FF1 ,
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE ,
    REJECT_VALUE = 0
) ;
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the definition of your external data source DS1. The data source must specify the container, and the location must specify the path within that container. It would help if you could take a screenshot of the container through the Explorer view in the portal, or using Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: BTW, you are using two different locations in those screenshots. Which is correct?

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ds1
WITH
  (  LOCATION = 'wasbs://test2@store17.blob.core.windows.net' 
     ,  CREDENTIAL = cred1 
     , TYPE = HADOOP )

Comment: Are you using ADLS Gen2 with hierarchic file system? If so, use "abfss" instead of "wasbs" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction-abfs-uri

Comment: No @RonDunn I am using simple blob storage and containers.

Comment: Hi @MoulshreeSuhas, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If we guess right, you want to load `SampleData.csv` from Blog Storage to Azure SQL Data warehouse.

When we [create an external data source with CREDENTIAL option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest#syntax-2) from Blob Storage:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <data_source_name>
WITH
  ( [ LOCATION = '<prefix>://<path>[:<port>]' ]
    [ [ , ] CREDENTIAL = <credential_name> ]
    [ [ , ] TYPE = HADOOP ]
[ ; ]
```

The location value format should be:

```
LOCATION = 'wasb[s]://<container>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net'
```

Then create the CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE, since we have set the container, just need set the /folder/filename in `LOCATION` directly like bellow( if 'store17' is container name):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[exttest1]
( [description] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [industry] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [level] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [size] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [line_code] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](4000) NULL )
WITH
(
    LOCATION='/test2/SampleData.csv' , --/folder/file
    DATA_SOURCE = ds1 ,
    FILE_FORMAT = FF1 ,
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE ,
    REJECT_VALUE = 0
) ;
```

But from your second screenshot, why the lLOCATION changed to `/test2/`?

Here's  the full code example which I load a `dbotest.csv` to my ADW, I tested and works well:

**CSV file:**
[image]

**T-SQL code:**

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AzureStorageCredential
WITH
  IDENTITY = '****', --Storage account name
  SECRET = '*****' ;--accournt key

-- Create an external data source with CREDENTIAL option.
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureStorage
WITH
  ( LOCATION = 'wasbs://testcontainer@****.blob.core.windows.net/' ,--
    CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential ,
    TYPE = HADOOP 
  ) ;

  --Create external file format
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT TextFileFormat
WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
      FORMAT_OPTIONS(
          FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
          STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
          USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = True)
)

---Create external table wiht format
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[dbotest]
( [id] int,
  [name] nvarchar(50)
  )
WITH
(
    LOCATION='/csv/dbotest.csv' ,--/folder/filename
    DATA_SOURCE = MyAzureStorage ,
    FILE_FORMAT = TextFileFormat ,
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE ,
    REJECT_VALUE = 0
) ;
```

**Data check**:

[image]

Hope this helps.